# How to build PhoneJS application for Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, cordova, devexpress, phonejs

I try PhoneGap Build service to create package for my Javascript application (in fact it is demo from [PhoneJS](http://phonejs.devexpress.com) distribution), but the package does not install to my Nokia Lumia device.

How do you build your PhoneGap applications for Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also use the standard PhoneGap approach to building Windows Phone 8 packages. It is described in the [Getting Started with Windows Phone 8](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_getting-started_windows-phone-8_index.md.html) article at Cordova site.

(however this also implies that you have Visual Studio installed, and WP8 SDK)

Comment: Indeed the most obvious way, how can I miss it. I mark this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DevExtreme to build PhoneJS application into Windows Phone 8 native package.

Please check this [article](http://help.devexpress.com/DevExtreme/Howto/Packaging#Build_Package_for_Win8Phone) for more details.

Comment: Thank you TSV! Do I need Visual Studio for this tool?

Comment: Unfortunately no, Raleigh :(